# Child view move out from parent view and does not respond to pressing, Android

Tags: android, layout, view, parent, intercept

After animation button moves out from parent layout and does not respond to touch. I tried to use TouchDelegate for extending  a view's touchable area, but it did not work in my case. I need it to scale (parent layout with all childs), and I do not want to change the size parent layout. Whether it is possible to solve this problem?

[thear scheme of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpqHL.png)

Comment: Can you include the code you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use TouchDelegate for Parent view and check window location coordinate for child views. When there is a pressing on the ParetView, I check to see if in the same place a childView, and if so, then move it.